# How to use the 'default' struct tag with Go's envconfig library?

Tags: go, environment-variables

I'm trying to use the `envconfig` library, https://github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig, in a program where most of the configuration variables have default values which I would only like to override if specific environment variables are set.

I've tried to run the following example program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig"
)

type config struct {
    foo string `default:"bar"`
}

func main() {
    var cfg config
    if err := envconfig.Process("app", &cfg); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(cfg.foo)
}
```

without the `APP_FOO` environment variable set:

```
> echo $APP_FOO
```

However, this does not print `bar` as I would expect it to:

```
> go run use_envconfig.go
```

I don't see how my implementation is different from the documented example at https://github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig#struct-tag-support to which the following comment pertains:

> If envconfig can't find an environment variable value for `MYAPP_DEFAULTVAR`, it will populate it with "foobar" as a default value.

How can I make this program so that the `cfg`'s value of `foo` is `bar` unless I set the `APP_FOO` environment variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your answer you accidentally fixed the problem. It's not `config` that needs to be capitalized. It is `Foo`. The following works: [Demo](https://play.golang.com/p/7tBUjHlJRS1).

```
type config struct {
    Foo string `default:"bar"`
}
```

In Go, only the capitalized fields are accessible outside the current package. Envconfig can only access capitalized fields. Think of those as private and public properties.

Lowercase is private, Uppercase is public.

Answer (score 1):

A little experimentation showed that both `config` and `foo` should be capitalized (to `Config` and `Foo`, respectively). The following program,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig"
)

type Config struct {
    Foo string `default:"bar"`
}

func main() {
    var cfg Config
    if err := envconfig.Process("app", &cfg); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(cfg.Foo)
}
```

produces `bar` as expected:

```
> go run use_envconfig.go
bar
```